# Does iOS clean keychain items automatically?

Tags: ios, keychain

I use [KeychainItemWrapper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html) to store an identifier of my users in `keychain` of iOS. I noticed that when we uninstall the app, the identifier persist in the `keychain` yet; but I'm wonder Does iOS will clean the items automatically when the `keychain` goes so big? or some other applications can remove or access the items?

Comment: As far as I know everything will stay until you reset the device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be deleted if the device is wiped or restored, whatever that resets your device.

Access to the keychain is tied to the provisioning profile used to sign the app. Consequently no other apps would be able to access that app's keychain info. This answers your question about some other App being able to access your App's  keychain items or not.

For reference: [Same Question on Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/36442)

Comment: It stays there intentionally. That way an app can intentionally store settings that will survive when the app is removed and re-installed. Items in user defaults get erased when the app is removed.